# add_menu_page does not seem to work in a class

Tags: plugins, add-menu-page

Here is some of my code:

```
class proposal {

function __construct() {
    add_menu_page('Topic Proposal', 'Topic Proposal', 'read', 'topic_proposal', array(&$this, 'writer_page'), 'dashicons-welcome-add-page');
}

public function load_menu() {
    echo 'EHY';
}

public function writer_page() {
    ?>
        <h1>Topic Proposal</h1>
    <?php
}

public function editor_page() {
    ?>
        <h1>Topic Proposal</h1>
    <?php
}

}

add_action( 'admin_init', function(){return new proposal();});
```

The "Topic Proposal" shows of on the menu but when I click on it I get this:

```
You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you read [`add_menu_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page) in codex?

Comment: I imagine. The "Topic Proposal" does show in the menu so in parts "add_menu_page" works it's just when I try to open the page it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`add_menu_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page) in Codex:

> Note: If you're running into the "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page" error, then you've hooked too early. The hook you should use is admin_menu.

`admin_init` is too early to hook `add_menu_page`, use `admin_menu`.